# Have any nations returned to their ancient homelands?

Tags: migration, nationalism

Over millennia, many nations have moved from place to place. For example, the [Romani People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people) migrated from the Indian subcontinent towards Europe. Many other nations have undergone similar migrations. **Have any of these nations returned to their ancient homeland?**

Of course, our genetic beings as humans all came from Africa, this question does not contradict that fact. But our cultures and customs - the things that make a group of people a nation - do have origins in differing places on the planet. That is why I use the term "nation" in the question, and not the term "people". I do refer to the nation of the Romani People how they refer to themselves. The word "People" in that sentence is part of a proper noun, and clearly a synonym of the term "nation" in that context.

Comment: It's worth noting that there really isn't a thing like an *original* homeland. We all came from somewhere else...somewhere in Africa, if you go back far enough. And with many places in between: our ancestors have moved and moved and moved. You can ask if a people has returned to a homeland especially important to them, or to the oldest known location, but not more.

Comment: @MarkOlson Our genetic beings as humans, yes, all came from Africa. But our cultures and customs - the things that make a group of people a nation - do have origins in differing places on the planet. That is why I use the term "nation" in the question, and not the term "people".

Comment: You in fact did use the term "people" when you said "Romani People." I don't think you've thought this question and all its implications thoroughly.

Comment: Using the terms "millenia" and "nation" in the same context also bears questions. As far as I understand, the Romans used the word "natio" as an exonym, and the use as an endonym only appeared in the late middle ages. Would you include groups that never thought of themselves as "nation"? What are your criteria? Note that by the accepted answer to [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/) the answer given here about Israel would **not** be right, since the Jewish people (the term of the Declaration of Independence) are not connected by birth(place), but by religion.

Comment: @cmw Yes, I referred to the nation of the Romani People how they refer to themselves. The word "People" in that sentence is part of a proper noun, and clearly a synonym of the term "nation" in that context.

Comment: @MCW Thank you, I've added my comments into the question. Yes, I agree that the question is much better now with the additional clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state of Israel was founded in the late 1940s.  There were already many Jews living in in Palestine where their ancestors had lived for centuries.

But most of the population emigrated there from countries all over the world, and the ancestors of most of the population  had not lived there for about two thousand years.